# How to display different color in html retrived from database?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have 15 or more rows in mysql database. I want to retrieve them and display in 2 different colors.

For First row `<tr><td height="30" bgcolor="#F5F5F5">....</td></tr>`
For second row `<td height="30" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">....</td></tr>`
For third row `<td height="30" bgcolor="#F5F5F5">....</td></tr>`
 
For Forth row `<td height="30" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">....</td></tr>`

 And so on....

How to display them in such order using php

Comment: What kind of Database?

Comment: mysql database. I am using xamp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSS selectors:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #F5F5F5;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #FFF;
}
```

Sample:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_nth-child_odd_even

Comment: How it works? And i have more tables used for another purpose.

Comment: @Mr.Shrestha please read this [article](https://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/)

Answer (score 0):

You first need to fetch rows from database in your php script and then in php you can loop these rows and apply an odd or even class, I have made an example script using php array. In your case $items will contain rows fetched from DB.

```
$items = array("abc", "123", "def", "345", 'wer'); 
foreach($items as $key => $val) {
    if($key == 0 ) {
        $class = 'odd';
    }
    elseif($key%2 == 0) {
        $class = 'odd';     
    }
    else {
        $class = 'even';    
    }

    echo $class . " $val" ."<br/>";
}
```

Let me know if it help you.